# checking if a div is empty and ignoring white spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if a div is empty and ignore white spaces.
If you type one or more spaces inside the below div and click the button, it logs "empty" instead of "not empty".

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
let a = $('#wrap').html();
if(a == '' || a.trim() == ''){console.log('empty');}
else{console.log('not empty');}
});
```

```css
.wrap{
background:gold;
min-height:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap' id='wrap' contenteditable></div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: *"let a = $('#wrap').html();"* should be `let a = $('#wrap').val();`, since you need the value

Comment: @SaymoinSam, this is not an input but a div

Comment: Sorry didn't see that it's a div and no input is there, that makes `.text()` suitable in this case

Comment: seems solved, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) instead. Also, the first check for an empty string is superfluous. The root cause of this issue is that spaces are represented as `&nbsp;` in HTML, which you can see if you `console.log(a)`.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  let a = $('#wrap').text();
  if (a.trim() == '') {//or simply, if(!a.trim()){
    console.log('empty');
  } else {
    console.log('not empty');
  }
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  background: gold;
  min-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap' id='wrap' contenteditable></div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply jQuery [.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) to check for length of any text in div. This will avoid (not count) spaces.

The way `.html()` works is that it will count white spaces as well.

Run snippet below.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  let a = $('#wrap').text();
  if (a == '' || a.trim() == '') {
    console.log('empty');
  } else {
    console.log('not empty');
  }
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  background: gold;
  min-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap' id='wrap' contenteditable></div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```